# Adjusting spacing between subplots

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have used the .subplot_adjust() function to adjust the spacing between subplots, so that text wouldn't overlap with each other. However it's not quite working out, any ideas perhaps why?.

```
def plot_TSPoly(self,x_ts,y_ts):

    fig = plt.Figure(figsize = (12,6))

    plt.subplot(2,1,1)
    plt.plot(x_ts,y_ts, c = 'blue')
    plt.xlabel('time')
    plt.ylabel('ndvi')
    plt.title('Time Series')

    plt.subplot(2,1,2)
    plt.plot(self.xx,self.yy, c = 'red')
    plt.xlabel('Time Since Eruption (months)')
    plt.ylabel('cumulative ndvi')
    plt.title('Anomaly')

    fig.subplots_adjust(hspace = 10, wspace = 10)


    plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following changes:

- Replace `plt.Figure` by `plt.figure`
- Then reduce the `hspace` value to 0.4 (or 0.5 or whatever you prefer)

---

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4, wspace=10)
```

Alternatively, you can use `fig.tight_layout()` as

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))

# Your two subplots here 

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```